# Mod rewrite trailing slash issue

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have this rules:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)$ /products.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/$ /products.php
RewriteRule ^store$ /products.php
```

And then in PHP I have this:

```
$paramCount = 0;

if(isset($_GET['param1']){ $param1 = $_GET['param1']; $paramCount++; }
if(isset($_GET['param2']){ $param2 = $_GET['param2']; $paramCount++; }
if(isset($_GET['param3']){ $param3 = $_GET['param3']; $paramCount++; }
```

Now with this URL:

https://mywebsite.com/store/

`$paramCount` should be 0 but it's 1, however with this one:

https://mywebsite.com/store

`$paramCount` is 0 (which is correct).

Same with this one:

https://mywebsite.com/store/pc-parts/

`$paramCount` is 2 when it should be 1, but with this one:

https://mywebsite.com/store/pc-parts

`$paramCount` is 1 (which is correct).

So the trailing slash is breaking it, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at the rewritelog to determine which rule gets invoked when? Or alternatively at your rules (and their ordering) to figure out why your parameter number expectations don't match up? Why are you using the `*` quantifier?

Comment: `paramx` is not a good parameter structure. I hope that is just for here.

Comment: @user3783243 i know it's terrible but it's just for here and is to fix something that should've been fixed yesterday!

Comment: @mario don't have access to the rewritelog, I barely understand mod_rewrite, I used some online tool to generate the rules. I suspect the issue can be fixed by tweaking the current rules but I don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

Well after some trial and error I figured it out, I reversed the order and added a trailing slash to each rule so it matches that one first:

```
RewriteRule ^store$ /products.php
RewriteRule ^store/$ /products.php
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)$ /products.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/$ /products.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /products.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /products.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
```

Not sure if it's the best solution but it works for my case